No such activation function "sum" when using the NEAT algorithm
I'm implementing the NEAT algorithm in python. I have a config file where I clearly declare the aggregation function and the activation function, here they are:
[DefaultGenome]
feed_forward = True


activation_default = sigmoid
activation_mutate_rate = 0.1



aggregation_default = sum
aggregation_mutate_rate = 0.1

However, it keeps giving me the error after generation 0 that it could not find the activation function "sum".
I've tried changing the names of the config parameters to just activation and aggregation, but that hasn't worked. Also, I looked on the NEAT documentation and the parameters were defined exactly as I had defined above, so I don't understand what the issue here is.
